# Bundling querysting token is not being generated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

I'm trying the new Web.Optimizations bundling and minimizer and have followed the examples but it is not generating the token portion of the query string:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/test")
    .Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"
    )
);
```

But the rendered HTML is

```
<script src="/Scripts/test" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What happened to the query string token?  I expected it to render something like

```
<script src="/Scripts/test?v=8HZAB6C8ZnrIPYNFzMQKt0AR4AUsUYBjxPPkbGSRIZo1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I do have debug set to false in web.config

EDIT: Just to clarify - the bundling and minimization DOES work.  But it is not generating a querystring token in the form of `?v=random`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in debug it does not bundle. Debug must be turned off to get it to bundle using the token.

From [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification):

> Bundling and minification is enabled or disabled by setting the value
>   of the debug attribute in the compilation Element  in the Web.config
>   file

You can override that behavior with:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Comment: Check the "Controlling Bundling and Minification" section: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: The bundling and minimization does work. But it is not generating a querystring token in the form of ?v=random

Comment: @JK Probably because you didn't use Styles.Render method.

Comment: @JK. It's defined in System.Web.Optimization namespace and it should not require Razor. Import the namespace in your view and call it like a regular method.

Comment: +1 Thanks, `<%= Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/test") %>` solved it

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Styles.Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.styles.render.aspx) method in your view:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Scripts/test")
```

You also need to disable debug mode from Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```